# jQuery's .data() getter only gets elements that are set initially with a value

Tags: jquery

... but if the value is originally empty like "" the value can not be changed using the same key !

```
function loadDialog(link, e, ajaxRequest) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var $title = link.innerHTML;
    var $contenturl = $(link).attr('href');
    var $dialog = $('<div id="MyDialog"></div>');

    // Read value from hidden input field
    var templateIdValue = $('input[name=TemplateId]').val();     

    // Change the value: This will always and only happen the 2nd time I come here,
    // the first time the templateIdValue will always be empty
    if (templateIdValue != '') {
        templateIdValue = 777;
    }

    $dialog.load($contenturl).data('templateIdKey', templateIdValue).dialog({
        title: $title,
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,               
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {debugger;
                ajaxRequest($(this), $('form', this));
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $dialog.dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When the 2nd time the templateIdValue is changed to 777

I come to this code:

Here I retrieve again the value and it should be 777. But its NOT. its empty !

```
@model ITMS.Web.Models.UnitViewModel

@*Remote Validation*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var templateId = $('#MyDialog').data('templateIdKey');
        $('input[name=TemplateId]').val(templateId);      
    }); 

</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Unit"))
{ 
     @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <p class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</p>
    <p class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)</p>
    <p class="editor-field">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</p> 

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TemplateId)    
}
```

How can I change the value of the key I passed the first time with the .data() method?

**UPDATE**

```
  // Does not cache the ajax requests to the controller e.g. IE7/8/9 is doing that...
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#OpenTemplate').click(function (event) { loadDialog(this, event, openTemplate); });
        $('#CreateTemplate').click(function (event) { loadDialog(this, event, createTemplate); });
        $('#DeleteTemplate').click(function (event) { loadDialog(this, event, deleteTemplate); });

        $('#CreateUnit').click(function (event) { loadDialog(this, event, createUnit); });
        $('#DeleteUnit').click(function (event) { deleteUnit(); });

        $('#CreateTeststep').click(function (event) { loadDialog(this, event, createTeststep); });
        $('#DeleteTeststep').click(function (event) { deleteTeststep(); });

        $('#SaveTemplate').click(function (event) { saveTemplate(); });    
    });
```

Comment: _"but if the value is originally empty"_ - If _what_ value is originally empty? `.data()` does _not_ create or update `data-` attributes on the element if that's what you mean. Where is `loadDialog()` called from?

Comment: yes, it probably stores in $.cache. This was very confusing for me too!

Comment: @nnnnnn the value 'templateIdValue' passed together with the templateIdKey to the .data(key,value) method. loadDialog() is a generic function and called for every click on an a-tag(link).

Comment: OK, but where is `loadDialog()` called from? Is it called after the document.ready handler that tries to use the value?

Comment: @n*6 I updated my initial post!

Comment: Does there not exist any method where I can set a key and change its value like I want?

Comment: The `.data()` function most definitely allows you to update values. I use it extensively and it works just fine.

Comment: In the "update" to your question, there are no calls to `.data()` at all.

Comment: @Pointy I thought I can update the value by using .data(key,value) again and again but it seems I can not. How do YOU update a value if it works for you? Actually my values are updated but ONLY if the initial value is NOT empty!

Comment: I think there must be some serious confusion; the `.data()` mechanism is very simple and it is quite reliable. [Here is a simple jsfiddle to demonstrate.](http://jsfiddle.net/EwrP6/) The code you have posted is extremely confusing and it is not at all clear what it is you're doing or expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your question rather confusing even after the update, so I still don't really understand what you're trying to do, but there seems to be two big problems with the way you're using `.data()`.

The first problem is that you retrieve the value in a document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var templateId = $('#MyDialog').data('templateIdKey');
```

...but the value isn't stored until the `loadDialog()` function is called in response to a click so naturally there could be no data against that key at that time since no clicks have been processed yet.

Secondly, you call the same `loadDialog()` function each time any of several elements is clicked, but each time `loadDialog()` is called it creates a new `"MyDialog"` div and then uses `.data()` to associate a key and value with that new div:

```
var $dialog = $('<div id="MyDialog"></div>');
// other code, then
$dialog.load($contenturl).data('templateIdKey', templateIdValue)
```

Again, your question isn't clear but you *seem* to be saying that you expect this to update the value stored for the previously created `"MyDialog"` div but `.data()` associated values with individual elements. Why do you recreate the dialog div every time?

Comment: I have changed my link/dialog creation and now the .data() works fine for me. I have removed the general loadDialog function for now and setup each dialog one time for each dialog call e.g. a dialog setup for openTemplate, createTemplate, etc... ah I just now realize that I recreated it everytime :P